# any real performance gain of setting affinity mask for threads?

Tags: multithreading, performance

actually, subject. when is it reasonable?

any difference between linux and windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [example](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/performance.php?test=chameneosredux) (it's just a benchmark) where it's possible to get a real performance gain when setting affinity of threads (they get ~10x gain in performance with affinity and some other hacks).

In this benchmark affinity settings at least allow utilizing the Core Quad's feature that it is really two dual core processors so the price of communication between different cores is not the same.

They run two parallel simulations to rid of expensive interaction between pairs of cores. Each simulation runs on its pair of cores and here affinity helps again to avoid (as was said in other answers) moving threads from one core to another and back.

Comment: +1, interesting example. any link about used other hacks and actual affinity usage?

Comment: http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/3539197.1.aspx here is an excellent article about a C implementation but it's in Russian. It can be translated with Google Translate: http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rsdn.ru%2Fforum%2Fcpp%2F3539197.1.aspx

Comment: You said "affinity helps again to avoid (as was said in other answers) moving threads from one core to another and back.". You meant from one core(corresponding to one CPU ) to another core(corresponding to another CPU ) , am I right?

Answer (score 1):

When you believe you can outsmart the scheduler. This should be pretty rare.

Comment: ic, but scheduler knows little about my program and environment. consider threads number = hardware parallelism, and dedicated server. won't attaching threads to different cores eliminate some sporadical context switches caused by system threads?

Comment: @robin It will not eliminate context switches as what core it runs on (i.e. its affinity) is not about how long it runs for, or whether it can be interrupted. What you may get is the fact that the thread may still have some hot memory in local cache if it gets rescheduled back to the same core (and the architecture supports local cache per core).

Comment: @chibacity: hot cache is good point, tnx. about context switches - i thought about some system thread that interrupts a program thread. if the program thread is attached to a core - it will return back so we have 2 switches. if not, it can then interrupt another program thread, not sure if scheduler handles such cases perfectly

Comment: @robin The scheduler does not take affinity into account when descheduling another thread.

Comment: @chibacity: hm, what platform do you mean? what is affinity for in such case? to run on some cpu until first context switch?

Comment: @robin You are describing an aspect of scheduling, I am talking about de-scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

At some point we were automating Microsoft Word to do some batch processing and it was crashing randomly on multi-cpu systems.  We figured it was a concurrent memory access bug and started setting Word process affinity to only run on a single core.  It resolved the issue.
I know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but decided to share :)

Answer (score 0):

As MK said the only conditions when this is necessary is if you feel that your application only needs to run on a set amount of cores. Which in his example is reasonable. In other cases you want to have your application avoid bottlenecking a system, for instance lets say your process runs concurrently on 4 cores of a quad core machine, which causes other programs that may be doing activity to have to wait extra time. You could instead set your program to only use 2 of the cores to allow the other 2 cores to process other important information from different applications. Most of the time you will not need to do this unless there are specific needs or if your application needs certain performance tweaks to run efficiently by itself or with other applications.

Comment: It all boils down to what your application will do, in some cases it's better to use mutexes and in others spinlock will do just fine. Thread priority can be used in situations like so : I have Task 1, 2, 3. I am currently running task 1 and 2. Once task 1 finishes i can then do task 3, so in that cause you may want to set task 1 as a higher priority for the time being so that you can finish the tasks quicker. Again this all depends heavily on the application and what needs to be accomplished.